# About eigenvalues, matrix equation with non invertible matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let A,B be two non-invertible square matrices of the same size.

Would there be a general procedure for solving the equation

$$ Ax = Bkx $$ 
for both $k$ and $x$? ($k$ is a scalar).

For example, if B were invertible, we could rewrite the equation as
$$B^{-1}Ax = kx$$ 
and then we could just solve for the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $B^{-1}A$. Is there any way to approach this problem if $A$ and $B$ are not invertible?

Comment: Not sure if it can help, but you can write the previus equaton as $(A-kB)x=0$, hence you can just have a look in its kernel

Answer (score 1):

If you consider $x$ in the kernel of $B$, then $Bkx$ will be zero; unless $x$ is also in the kernel of $A$, this cannot be a solution. So solutions come in two classes:

- Those in $Ker(B) \cap Ker(A)$, and
- Those not in $Ker(B)$.

For those in the second group, you can take the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse $H$ of $B$, and for these, $HBx = x$, so you can write
$$
(HA)x = k(HB)x = kx
$$
and merely look for eigenvectors of the matrix $HA$.

Comment: This seems like a good approach. Where could I find some more documentation about the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse, especially this left-sided one?

Comment: You could google "Moore Penrose Pseudoinverse", which would lead you to a wikipedia article, which would in turn point you to multiple references.